# my login code broke in some way

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

my code is simple... ish

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("login")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)


label_1 = Label(root, text="username")
label_2 = Label(root, text="password")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root, show="*")
c_1 = Checkbutton(root, text="keep me loged in")

a = entry_1.get()
b = entry_2.get()

def log_in():
    print (a,b)

button_1 = Button(root, text="log in", command=log_in)

label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=1)

entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

c_1.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

button_1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

When you hit the login button it is supposed to recall what you typed later it will not print it but I have it like that for debugging so I can see if it works and no it does not.

when i run the program no matter what i put in the entry i get ' ' for A and B
i ran it again with a slightly different code but still did not work all i changed was

```
button_1 = Button(root, text="log in", command=log_in)
```

to

```
button_1 = Button(root, text="log in", text=a,b)
```

im going to have a if statement where

```
if a == "something here":
    if b == "something here":
        print "you are %s" % (raw_input("name?\n:"))
```

and then finish with an else statement but for now til i get it working ill leave it as print (a,b)

Comment: You say it broke, but you are not saying how. What is not working? What was working before?

Comment: when i run it it does not print 'a and b' it worked kinda but i jest got here and im getting errors

Comment: Please clearly describe **exactly** what the problem is. Also include your input, the output you are getting (including the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks), and the output you are expecting. **Do not** put this info into the comments, [edit] your question instead. Also, instead of vague run-on sentences, please be clear and precise in your terminology, using proper grammar and punctuation.

Comment: As a quick guess, I gather you're trying to have the program remember what you typed and display it later, is that correct? Your code has a distinct lack of functionality to accomplish this task, so I would suggest implementing it.

Comment: OK, let's try again. Please *attempt* to use punctuation. Any at all. Please complete your thoughts - your question now ends with "*... finish with an else statement but*" But what? You're not making any sense. `Button(root, text="log in", text=a,b)` will not do what you (I assume) want it to do, because the comma `,` indicates an argument separator, like after `root` and `"log in"`. `text=(a,b)` *may* work, but I doubt it - if `a` and `b` are strings you'll have to concatenate them.

Comment: The very good thing you do is include a complete running code. But your explanations are bad: in one question on SO, you should focus on one thing and be crystal-clear. Here you may have said: "When I press the log-in button, nothing is printed, even if I have typed some characters in Entries  entry_1 and entry_2."

Comment: Don't vote down, teach him ! think a tree, maybe give fruit 20 years later and maybe you can't eat them. Humans are animal when destroying teaching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def log_in():
    print (a,b)

button_1 = Button(root, text="log in", command=log_in)
```

TO

```
def log_in(a,b):
        print (a,b)

button_1 = Button(root, text="log in", command=lambda: log_in(entry_1.get(),entry_2.get()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You must define a (and b) inside your log-in function.
Or you may use a StringVar variable.

The simplest solution:

```
def log_in():
    a = entry_1.get()
    b = entry_2.get()
    print (a,b)
```